# Why must local({...}) be defined using two rounds of expression quoting?

Tags: r, non-standard-evaluation, r-environment

I'm trying to understand how R's `local` function is working. With it, you can open a temporary local scope, which means what happens in `local` (most notably, variable definitions), stays in `local`. Only the last value of the block is returned to the outside world. So:

```
x <- local({
    a <- 2
    a * 2
}) 

x
## [1] 4

a
## Error: object 'a' not found
```

`local` is defined like this:

```
local <- function(expr, envir = new.env()){
    eval.parent(substitute(eval(quote(expr), envir)))
}
```

As I understand it, two rounds of expression quoting and subsequent evaluation happen:

1. `eval(quote([whatever expr input]), [whatever envir input])` is generated as an unevaluated call by `substitute`.
2. The call is evaluated in `local`'s caller frame (which is in our case, the Global Environment), so
   `[whatever expr input]` is evaluated in `[whatever envir input]`

However, I do not understand why step 2 is nessecary. Why can't I simply define `local` like this:

```
local2 <- function(expr, envir = new.env()){
    eval(quote(expr), envir)
}
```

I would think it evaluates the expression `expr` in an empty environment? So any variable defined in `expr` should exist in `envir` and therefore vanish after the end of `local2`?

However, if I try this, I get:

```
x <- local2({
    a <- 2
    a * 2
}) 
x
## [1] 4
a
## [1] 2
```

So `a` leaks to the Global Environment. Why is this?

**EDIT:** Even more mysterious: Why does it not happen for:

```
eval(quote({a <- 2; a*2}), new.env())
## [1]  4
a
## Error: object 'a' not found
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Parameters to R functions are passed as promises. They are not evaluated unless the value is specifically requested. So look at

```
# clean up first
if exists("a") rm(a)

f <- function(x) print(1)
f(a<-1)
# [1] 1
a
# Error: object 'a' not found
g <- function(x) print(x)
g(a<-1)
# [1] 1
a
# [1] 1
```

Note that in the `g()` function, we are using the value passed to the function which is that assignment to `a` so that creates `a` in the global environment. With `f()`, that variable is never created because that function parameter remained a promise end was never evaluated.

If you want to access a parameter without evaluating it, you need to use something like `match.call()` or `subsititute()`. The `local()` function does the latter.

If you remove the `eval.parent()`, you'll see that the substitute puts the un-evaluated expression from the parameter into a new call to `eval()`.

```
h <- function(expr, envir = new.env()){
    substitute(eval(quote(expr), envir))
}
h(a<-1)
# eval(quote(a <- 1), new.env())
```

Where as if you do

```
j<- function(x) {
  quote(x)
}
j(a<-1)
# x
```

you are not really creating a new function call. Further more when you `eval()` that expression, you are triggering the evaluation of `x` from it's original calling environment (triggering the evaluation of the promise), not evaluating the expression in a new environment.

`local()` then uses the `eval.parent()` so that you can use existing variables in the environment within your block. For example

```
b<-5
local({
  a <- b
  a * 2
})
# [1] 10
```

Look at the behaviors here

```
local2 <- function(expr, envir = new.env()){
    eval(quote(expr), envir)
}
local2({a<-5; a})
# [1] 5
local2({a<-5; a}, list(a=100, expr="hello"))
# [1] "hello"
```

See how when we use a non-empty environment, the `eval()` is looking up `expr` in the environment, it's not evaluating your code block in the environment.

Comment: Thank you, the hint with the promise arguments already helped a lot. However, I cannot follow your interpretation of the `eval.parent` call. You state it is that variables in the calling scope (so the Global Env) can be used. However, the same seems to be possible with `local3 <- function(expr, envir = new.env()){
    eval(substitute(expr),envir)
}`, to test with `d <- 5; x <- local3({a <- 2; a * d + e;}, list(a=100, expr=20, e=1)); x; a` `x` has the correct value 11 and `a` stays local.

Comment: It's just more explicit I suppose. If you look at the default for `eval()`, if you provide an environment to the `envir` parameter as you do, it defaults to assuming an enclosing environment of `enclos=parent.frame()`. You could change that behavior with `enclos=baseenv()`